# Neo4jPhp count Result retrieval

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

In Neo4jPhp, to get the result we use

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['x']->getProperty('Name') . "<br>";
}
```

But when my query is

```
MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)
```

How to retrieve the result?

I tried

```
echo $row['x']->getProperty('0')
```

but it's not working. HOW TO GET THE COUNT RESULT as it do not have field name?

On using

```
echo $row['x']->getProperty('count(n)')<>
```

I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getProperty() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\index.php on line 17

Comment: Have you tried `getProperty('count(n)')`? That's usually the column name in other APIs when you don't assign an alias.

Comment: @jjaderberg- Yes tried but still not working
Error - Fatal error: Call to a member function getProperty() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\abcd\index.php on line 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your query to:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN count(n) AS c;
```

Then, try:

```
echo $row['c']
```

Comment: How about 'echo $row['c']'?

Comment: Just to clarify, the keys to the $row array object are the names of the returned values from the Cypher query.